# Content dispute on "How to draw a circuit diagram to check a 4 bits number is odd or even"

Tags: discussion

I noticed [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76595/how-to-draw-a-circuit-diagram-to-check-a-4-bits-number-is-odd-or-even) was locked by W5VO over a content dispute. But I'm not really sure what the dispute is about. Can someone shed some light on the lock?

Comment: How many revisions do you see? You make it sound like four revisions, but i see nine.

Comment: It does look to me like the nature of the question was changed by the OP. Regardless of whether that change falls within the previously ambiguous span of the question, it's still not tolerable IMO. It's a typical "Not my fault you didn't read my mind" edit by OP.

Comment: @W5VO, Erp, pardon my previous comment, I can see the revisions. Anyway, the number of revisions is irrelevant. It could be 100 revisions and still remain the same question.

Comment: I didn't get that impression. From what I saw he originally asked for a circuit for detecting if a number is odd or even. Even after all the edits the nature of the question seems the same to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, seeing the revisions is telling. It seems the OP was upset with the responses he got and attempted to burn his own question through destructive edits. I was confused because I didn't know I could see the revisions.

Comment: @trav1s The *nature* of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of mod tools, this is an example of only having a hammer to deal with a situation. Specifically, the user in question wanted to delete their question. The system won't allow you to delete your own question once you have answers, so they edited the question to remove all content. These changes were then rolled-back. This went back-and-forth a few times, and so I locked the page to keep the question intact.

Also, "locked" does not mean "closed". I don't intend to close this question for the very reasons you mention.

Comment: The problem is that Locked is essentially the same thing as closed, except it can't be voted to reopen. What's the practical difference?

Comment: We don't go through and delete old locked questions, and (relevant to this case) you can't edit the question.

Comment: Yeah, seeing the edits, I can understand why you would lock it to protect the question. But what about using punitive action against users who make such destructive edits? That way a lock wouldn't be necessary I would think. Or are bans only for the last resort?

Answer (score 1):

This could have been resolved much more simply if someone were willing to state the answer as a sum of products as requested.

It's the sum of a single product of a single input...

And no, that is not really a joke, since that's what the implementation really would look like if you have a sum-of-products type PLD.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. The correct order of operations would be truth table -> K-map -> SoP form -> logic minimization. That is probably what he wanted, and when people skipped straight to the end without going through those steps he stormed off in a huff, even though most of us just didn't realize what he wanted.

Comment: I think the mistake was the logic minimization - that wasn't asked for, and doing that technically does not answer the question asked, and may be incompatible with the implementation technology.  If I was going to draw something, I'd draw a one input AND gate feeding a one-input OR gate, since that illustrates what a degenerate case of SOP this would be, while still showing how that form of implementation can be used.

Comment: In fact, I did state the answer as a sum of products...and OP nonetheless edited his question to make it into a non-question.